# How would i call WCF Rest service which datacontract parameter from Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, wcf-rest

```
  [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(DcCustomFaultMessage))]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
     UriTemplate = "/GetHistoryData")]
    List<DcHistoryData> GetHistoryData(DcHistoryCriteria criteria);
```

or

With multiple parameters

```
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(DcCustomFaultMessage))]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
     UriTemplate = "/GetHistoy?ReportingId={ReportingId}&ErrorCode={ErrorCode}&OriginatorCode={OriginatorCode}&PrimaryAssetClass={PrimaryAssetClass}&MessageType={MessageType}&FeedbackType={FeedbackType}&ReportType={ReportType}&RegionCode={RegionCode}&errorstatus={errorstatus}")]
    Stream GetHistoryData(string ReportingId, string ErrorCode, string OriginatorCode, string PrimaryAssetClass, string MessageType, string FeedbackType, int ReportType, string RegionCode, string errorstatus);
```

Which is a better way to do it? How to call this from AngularJS?

I am able to call this service if the service is defined without parameter with below call from AngularJS:

```
 $http.get("http://localhost:55467/WCFServiceHost/DFAService.svc/GetHistorydata")
    .success(function (result) {
        alert('got history data');
        $scope.HistoryRejections = $.parseJSON(JSON.parse(result));    
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.attributesData = null;
        $scope.showmessage("error", "error");
    });
```

I don't know how to do this in case of multiple parameter or datacontract parameter? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HTTP GET request can't contain data to be posted to the server. However you can add a query string to the request.

angular.http provides an option for it params
You can use:

```
$http({
       url: yourURL, 
       method: "GET",
       params: {ReportingId: '', ErrorCode: ''}
});
```

Or if you want to use $http.get():

```
$http.get(yourURL, {
   params: {ReportingId: '', ErrorCode: ''}
});
```